# How do you overwrite a setter method of a has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create my own setter method for a Ruby on Rails has_and_belongs_to_many association.  This is what I've got so far:

```ruby
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  def tags= comma_separated_tags
    tag_objects = comma_separated_tags.split(',').collect do |tag_title|
      Tag.find_or_create_by(title: tag_title)
    end
    @tags = tag_objects # doesn't work
    # write_attribute(:tags, tag_objects) # raises an exception
  end
end
```

Is there a way to generate the records on the HABTM join table without using SQL?

Comment: I realized while preparing this question that it would be better in this case to collect the ActiveRecord Tag objects in my Controller rather than in the model which will allow me to use the default setter.

Comment: Probably, messing with the default setter sounds like something that may kick you in the nuts somewhere down the road. (such as when using factories)